# How to sort a List<String> containing multiple fields delimted by '|~'

Tags: java, sorting, comparator

I have a  `List<String> theList`
which has following kind of values

```
"2011-05-05|~JKED"
"2011-05-06|~ABC"
"2011-05-01|~XYZ"
"2011-05-01|~WWX"
```

As you could guess there are two "fields" in `theList`.

I want to sort  `theList` on first field and then on second field such as I get following output after sorting operation

```
"2011-05-01|~WWX"
"2011-05-01|~XYZ"
"2011-05-05|~JKED"
"2011-05-06|~ABC"
```

If I take these two fields in a separate lists and do `Collections.sort(field1List)` `Collections.sort(field2List)` I get the desired output.

**But,** I want to know, how to use `Collections.sort(theList, new Comparator(){})` to be able to sort above `theList` to get desired output. If it is not possible to solve through Comparator(), please suggest some method which might look like `sortMultiFieldList(List<String> theList)`

It is a long story why I **have to have** two or more fields in a single List.

Let me know if you need more clarification.

Comment: Something is wrong (or doesn't makes sense)
1 ) A List<string> can't have two fields. 2) Assuming you have fields in 1 list and others in the Second list. You need them related, i guess. And they aren't in any way.

Comment: @celerno:  If it's one giant string with the pipe in the middle, then essentially it does have two "fields".

Comment: Yep, well. Now its edited and it makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is remarkably straightforward.  You'll want to write a custom `Comparator` for this, and enforce its comparison logic to behave the way you want with respect to your two separate "fields".

The motivation here is that these fields are lexicographically compared to one another for the date portion, as well as the alphabetical string portion.  If you find that the date comparison isn't giving you accurate results (and it may not; I'm not sure of any cases that it wouldn't work off hand, though), then convert it to a `Date` and compare that in-line.

```
Collections.sort(entries, new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String left, String right) {
        String[] leftFragments = left.split("[|]");
        String[] rightFragments = right.split("[|]");
        if(leftFragments[0].compareTo(rightFragments[0]) == 0) {
            return leftFragments[1].compareTo(rightFragments[1]);
        } else {
            return leftFragments[0].compareTo(rightFragments[0]);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: +1 Thanks, I tried to simplify the question. Actually, some of my list has upto 4 "fields", it is not always just 2 fields. Does this solution work for list with more than 2 fields?

Comment: You would have to engineer it to do that.  Right now, the `String[]` would hold all four elements (if you had three `|` characters).  It does need to be uniform since this makes the assumption that you have at least two; if you want to assume that you have more than that, you'd need to include that here as well.